# Camgirl system with Node.js/socket.io and HTML5/WebRTC

Tags: html, node.js, socket.io, webrtc

A client has ordered me a camgirl system for his business.

I have written a little code to broadcast a videoconference to multiple users with WebRTC (HTML5) and socket.io, a node.js module. It works fine in the main actual browsers. It's capturing the video stream and drawing it to a canvas element and sending this picture in JPG format to the server. There the node.js app broadcasts it. All this fifteen times per second. Each frame weighs between 20 and 30 KB.

My question is: Will the server app's performance in a production environment (private server) match the demanded quality? I estimate there could be around 10 girls broadcasting and around 500-1000 users watching.

I know this could be calculated, but we also know that in production the results sometimes stray from what we expected.

Any advice will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: not much of a supporter of the whole thing with "cameras & girls" , but you should try to transmit binary through websocket, IMHO it should be a significant performance gain. Other than that, a flash fallback should be considered since the webrtc either lacks support on browsers or just "its too new".

Comment: Yes it's new, but not forever. I don't like the flash option because of iOS and my client's budget isn't much, so i'm looking for an universal solution. So binary, may you elaborate please?

Comment: Don't know if matches my needs but looks interesting. σας ευχαριστώ !

Comment: I've managed to broadcast the canvas images raw, with no base64, just using atob() and btoa() functions, and it works perfectly. I'm saving up to a 25% of traffic. Versions: node.js 0.10.20, socket.io 0.5.0.

Comment: have you tried to compress the images?

Comment: well, I'm retrieving the binary data from the canvas in JPG format 70% quality: "var d = $("#canvasLocal").get(0).toDataURL("image/jpeg", .7);" and that's a compression format, isn't it?

Comment: My challenge right now is broadcasting audio too, I'm scraping with the Web Audio API. I shall inform about my adventures :)